# Docker : Cannot access remote API

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-api

I am trying to enable the docker rest API and then access it from my local machine. I have docker setup on an ec2 instance. I edit the `ExecStart` line in my `/lib/systemd/systemd/docker.service`

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243
```

I then ran `systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo service docker restart` .

When I run `curl http://localhost:4243/version` from inside the server, I get the return I am looking for. But when I run `curl http://remote-machine-ip:4243/version` from my local system I get a `failed to connect` error. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you check your firewall? Both on the system, and the EC2 security group.

Comment: Yes I did. I added the rules to security group

Comment: Are you exposing that port in your Dockerfile?

Comment: Im not using a docker file. I installed docker on the ubuntu box and for now just want to expose the api

Comment: what is the output of `ufw status` and `iptables -S`?

Comment: ufw also shows the the rule added and is active....